# Remove gutter on masonry from last column

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout, gutter

I've got a fluid responsive isotope, masonry grid (also using images loaded - but not in this example), with breakpoints.

I want to remove the last gutter column, so there's no spacing on the right hand side, so it sits flush - but I can't work out the code.

I've setup an example here:
http://codepen.io/mattpark22/pen/yyzKgo

The main functions are:

```
colWidth = function () {
    $w = $container.width(), 
        columnNum = 1,
        columnWidth = 0;
    if ($w > 1400) {
        columnNum  = 7;
    } else if ($w > 1200) {
        columnNum  = 6;
    } else if ($w > 1000) {
        columnNum  = 5;
    } else if ($w > 800) {
        columnNum  = 4;
    } else if ($w > 600) {
        columnNum  = 3;
    } else if ($w > 300) {
        columnNum  = 2;
    }
    columnWidth = Math.floor($w/columnNum);
    $container.find('.isotope-item').each(function() {
        var $item = $(this),
            multiplier_w = $item.attr('class').match(/isotope-item-w(\d)/),
            multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/isotope-item-h(\d)/),
            width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-5 : columnWidth-5,
            height = multiplier_h ? columnWidth*multiplier_h[1]*0.45-5 : columnWidth*0.45-5;
        $item.css({
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
    });
    return columnWidth;
};
isotope = function () {
    $container.isotope({
        resizable: false,
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
        filter: hashFilter,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: colWidth(),
            gutterWidth: 5
        }
    });
};
```

Any ideas/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Isotope v2, the masonry `gutterWidth` option was changed to `gutter`.

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/QwqmRO

```
$container.isotope({
  isResizeBound: false,
  itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
  filter: hashFilter,
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: colWidth(),
    gutter: 5
  }
});
```

Also, the columnWidth function no longer works with Isotope v2. Use [element sizing](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing) instead